# Hartl Rails Tutorial, Chapter 8.3, Cucumber has 0 scenarios 0 steps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I'm working my way through Hartl's Rails Tutorial (http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#sec:cucumber).

I finished through chapter 9 and then decided to go back and do the optional Cucumber part in Chapter 8.3.

I added cucumber-rails and database_cleaner to the Gemfile:

```
group :test do
    gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
    gem 'rb-fsevent', '0.4.3.1', :require =     false
    gem 'growl', '1.0.3'
    gem 'factory_girl_rails', '1.4.0'
    gem 'cucumber-rails', '1.2.1', require: false
    gem 'database_cleaner', '0.7.0'
end
```

In terminal, I ran these commands:

```
bundle install
rails generate cucumber:install
```

Everything seemed to install just fine. Then I added the file 'signing_in.feature' to the 'features/' directory.

```
Feature: Signing in

    Scenario: Unsuccessful signin
        Given a user visits the signin page
        When he submits invalid signin information
        Then he should see an error message

    Scenario: Successful signin
        Given a user visits the signin page
            And the user has an account
            And the user submits valid signin information
        Then he should see his profile page
            And he should see a signout link
```

Then I ran this:

```
bundle exec cucumber features/
```

And here was the result in terminal:

```
Using the default profile...
Feature: Signing in

0 scenarios
0 steps
0m0.000s
```

I think I'm expecting there to be 2 scenarios and 2 failures. Is there a step that I left out? Could anything I added in chapter 9 interfere with this?

Thank you.

Comment: Realy strange bug. Can you try to lauch the features just with "cucumber feature/"

Comment: @Dougui, I just tried that and got this error: You have already activated cucumber-rails 1.3.0, but your Gemfile requires cucumber-rails 1.2.1. Using bundle exec may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)

Comment: Just a stupid question... Did you save your file?

Comment: I thought I did, but perhaps I didn't. Alright, I'm such a noob. I saved the cuke file again and it worked, or rather failed, as planned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may have not saved one of the files. I went back and saved it, and it now works as expected.

Nothing to see here, move along. :)